# Spring Boot Rest App on GAE throws an exception cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory"

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My Spring Boot Restservice App is running just fine in normal Spring App Context. But when I try to run it on Google App Engine the following Exception is thrown:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory
>   method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c05fbf5
>   cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

**here is the stacktrace of my exception:**

```
D:\Progs\JAVA\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:50742,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:D:/Progs/appengine-java-sdk/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:D:/Progs/appengine-java-sdk/lib/override/appengine-dev-jdk-overrides.jar -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "D:\Progs\appengine-java-sdk\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar;D:\Progs\JAVA\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\tools.jar;D:\Progs\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain -p 8080 --disable_update_check C:\Users\pk\Documents\ItelliJProjects\gps-trackman\target\gps-trackman-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50742', transport: 'socket'
Apr 18, 2015 11:38:05 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNUNG: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Apr 18, 2015 11:38:06 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFORMATION: Successfully processed C:\Users\pk\Documents\ItelliJProjects\gps-trackman\target\gps-trackman-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Apr 18, 2015 11:38:06 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFORMATION: Successfully processed C:\Users\pk\Documents\ItelliJProjects\gps-trackman\target\gps-trackman-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/web.xml
Apr 18, 2015 11:38:06 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFORMATION: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Connected to server
Apr 18, 2015 11:38:07 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFORMATION: jetty-6.1.x

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.3.RELEASE)

Apr 18, 2015 11:38:09 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
INFORMATION: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-04-18 11:38:09.421  INFO ??? --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1429349889417 ms
2015-04-18 11:38:09.439  INFO ??? --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on KABUL with PID ??? (C:\Users\pk\Documents\ItelliJProjects\gps-trackman\target\gps-trackman-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar started by pk in C:\Users\pk\Documents\ItelliJProjects\gps-trackman\target\gps-trackman-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
2015-04-18 11:38:09.529  INFO ??? --- [           main] onConfigNonEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.AnnotationConfigNonEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@73bad293: startup date [Sat Apr 18 11:38:09 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-04-18 11:38:14.349  INFO ??? --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-04-18 11:38:14.627  INFO ??? --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'entityManagerFactory': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=appConfig; factoryMethodName=entityManagerFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/pekam/AppConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=true; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=entityManagerFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]]
2015-04-18 11:38:18.744  INFO ??? --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2015-04-18 11:38:21.493  INFO ??? --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$563a5e93] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-04-18 11:38:21.629  INFO ??? --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-04-18 11:38:21.670  INFO ??? --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-04-18 11:38:21.691  INFO ??? --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-04-18 11:38:23.695  INFO ??? --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: org.h2.Driver
2015-04-18 11:38:23.696  INFO ??? --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2015-04-18 11:38:23.696  INFO ??? --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2015-04-18 11:38:29.289  INFO ??? --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-04-18 11:38:29.371  INFO ??? --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2015-04-18 11:38:29.759  INFO ??? --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
2015-04-18 11:38:29.764  INFO ??? --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-04-18 11:38:29.770  INFO ??? --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-04-18 11:38:30.586  INFO ??? --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-04-18 11:38:30.858  INFO ??? --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2015-04-18 11:38:31.435  INFO ??? --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2015-04-18 11:38:36.502  INFO ??? --- [           main] o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean     : Loading properties file from class path resource [rest-default-messages.properties]
2015-04-18 11:38:37.111  WARN ??? --- [           main] onConfigNonEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [com/pekam/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c05fbf5 cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(SpringBootContextLoaderListener.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:266)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:284)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:217)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c05fbf5 cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver$3.run(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c05fbf5 cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at com.pekam.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c2ce662.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at com.pekam.AppConfig.transactionManager(AppConfig.java:125)
    at com.pekam.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c2ce662.CGLIB$transactionManager$2(<generated>)
    at com.pekam.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c2ce662$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$97c35f17.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.pekam.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c2ce662.transactionManager(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 45 common frames omitted

2015-04-18 11:38:37.125  INFO ??? --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-04-18 11:38:37.139  WARN ??? --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)
2015-04-18 11:38:37.154 ERROR ??? --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [com/pekam/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c05fbf5 cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(SpringBootContextLoaderListener.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:266)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:284)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:217)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c05fbf5 cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver$3.run(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c05fbf5 cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at com.pekam.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c2ce662.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at com.pekam.AppConfig.transactionManager(AppConfig.java:125)
    at com.pekam.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c2ce662.CGLIB$transactionManager$2(<generated>)
    at com.pekam.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c2ce662$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$97c35f17.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.pekam.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c2ce662.transactionManager(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

**here is my code of the**

```
   package com.pekam;

    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.sql.DataSource;


    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("com.pekam")
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @EnableJpaRepositories



    public class AppConfig {
        @Resource
        Environment env;


    @Bean
    public DataSource MyDataSource() {

        //String str = com.pekam.Settings.this.dbUser;
        DriverManagerDataSource H2DataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        H2DataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        H2DataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:file:h2\\db");
        H2DataSource.setUsername("sa");
        H2DataSource.setPassword("");

    MsSqlDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");


    DriverManagerDataSource MySqlDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    MySqlDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        String url = null;

            MySqlDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
              MySqlDataSource.setUsername("pk");
                MySqlDataSource.setPassword("f7ka1");
                MySqlDataSource.setUrl(url);

        return MySqlDataSource;
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

  HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
  vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
  vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
  vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");


  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
  factory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
  factory.setPackagesToScan("com.pekam");
  factory.setDataSource(MyDataSource());
  factory.afterPropertiesSet();


  return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

  JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
  txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
  return txManager;
}


}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having the same problem today converting a part of a Spring application to a Spring Boot application.  The problem was that Spring kept loading a default `entityManagerFactory` bean.

In order to use my `entityManagerFactory` bean I had to return the instance of `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` directly, instead of returning `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`'s `getObject()`:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

  HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
  vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
  vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
  vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
  factory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
  factory.setPackagesToScan("com.pekam");
  factory.setDataSource(MyDataSource());
  factory.afterPropertiesSet();


  return factory;
}
```

and then in the configuration of the `transactionManager` bean call `entityManagerFactory().getObject()`:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

  JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
  txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
  return txManager;
}
```